# Communicating just one variable to a Node module

Tags: node.js

I have `app.js` and `routes.js`. In `app.js` I require `routes.js`. For `routes.js` to run, I just need to pass the single variable `app` to it. Is there a way to communicate `app` to `routes.js` without using `require` and `module.exports`? I'm looking for a syntax like

```
require(module, arguments);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, surely your code is wrapped into some function or class? If you have a class in `routes.js`

```
Routes = function(app) {}
```

Then you could do

```
require('routes.js');
var routes = new Routes(app);
routes.map(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Xeon06's solution, if `routes.js` exports a function, you can usually pass in the app as a regular argument, like so: `require('routes')(app)`.

Answer (score 0):

In app.js:

```
require('module')(arg1, arg2);
```

And in module/index.js:

```
module.exports = function(arg1, arg2) {
    // code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of require as a normal JavaScript function that returns a function or an object, depending on what you have.

In your case require('module') will return a function which you would then call with arguments (arg1, arg2) etc, for example:

```
require('module')(arg1, arg2);
```

You would have the following code structure in the module:

```
module.exports = function(arg1, arg2) {
  // your code here
}
```